# Extracting Current Bid Amounts using Beautfiul Soup - Dynamically Updating Values

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, scrape

This is my first introduction to both Python and BeautifulSoup. I am trying to scrape the current bid amount from a specific property listed on a popular auction website (RealInsight), but I can not get BeautifulSoup to pull the actual integer I am looking for, only the HTML code. I am looking for the value of the "s-b-n" class tag, which is $3,250,000 until the auction actually starts.

https://marketplace.realinsight.com/sales/details/XXX

I think this is because the value is dynamically updating and is being generated outside of the HTML code, but I'm not sure how to validate that thesis or get the value if that proves correct. I also think I might not be correctly referencing the table in which the value is contained, but again, not very experienced in python or bs4.

[UPDATED WITH FINAL CODE BELOW USING ewwink's METHOD - SCRAPE ONCE A SECOND FOR FIVE SECONDS] -UPDATED TO HANDLE AUCTION END-

```
import bs4
import time
import csv
import datetime
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
my_url = 'https://marketplace.realinsight.com/sales/details/XXX'
uclient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uclient.read()
uclient.close()
endmsg = "Auction End"
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
propname = page_soup.title.text
bids = page_soup.select_one(".body-content")
currentbid = bids['data-nb']
bidincrement = bids['data-bi']
with open(propname + '_bids.csv','w',newline='') as f:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f)
    thewriter.writerow(['i','prop_name','date_time','bid_increment','bid_amt'])
    for i in range(0,5,1):
            try:
                import sys
                sale = page_soup.select_one("div.sale-end-text")
                auctionend = sale.text.replace(" ", "")
                if auctionend == sale.text.replace(" ", ""):
                    currentDT = datetime.datetime.now()    
                    thewriter.writerow([i,endmsg,currentDT,currentbid])    
                    print(endmsg,currentbid)
                    time.sleep(1)
                    sys.exit()
                else:
                    print('will never get to this point')
            except Exception:
                pass

            currentDT = datetime.datetime.now()
            thewriter.writerow([i,propname,currentDT,bidincrement,currentbid])
            print(i,propname,currentDT,bidincrement,currentbid)
            time.sleep(1)
```

UPDATED WITH chitown88's method

```
import bs4
import datetime
import time
import csv
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Users\\XXXX\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://marketplace.realinsight.com/sales/details/XXX')
html = driver.page_source
page_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
bids = page_soup.select("td.s-b-n")
propname = page_soup.title.text
currentbid = bids[0].text
with open(propname + '_bids.csv','w',newline='') as f:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f)
    thewriter.writerow(['i','prop_name','date_time','bid_amt'])
    for i in range(0, 5, 1):
        currentDT = datetime.datetime.now()
        driver.refresh()
        thewriter.writerow([i, propname, currentDT, currentbid])
        print(i, propname, currentDT, currentbid)
        time.sleep(1)
driver.close()
```

I can see the number I am looking for ($3,250,000) within the HTML code, but it flashes and updates every few seconds, which is why I think it is generated elsewhere.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have the page load in before parsing. [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) is a perfect for that.

```
import bs4 
from selenium import webdriver 

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://marketplace.realinsight.com/sales/details/367')

html = driver.page_source
page_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

bids = page_soup.select("td.s-b-n")
bid = bids[0].text
print(bid)

driver.close()
```

and the output:

```
In [91]: print(bid)
$3,250,000
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Posted final code in update above.

Answer (score 1):

you can use BeautifulSoup there is `data-sb` attribute in `div.body-content` that store the bid value.

```
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
bids = page_soup.select_one(".body-content")

print(bids['data-sb'])
# format the number
print('${:,d}'.format(int(float(bids['data-sb']))))
print(bids.attrs)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Will post final code using this method above.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get BeautifulSoup to give me the data but I managed through Selenium. You must have the [chromedriver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.44/) installed as well as Selenium, you can do so by typing from the console:

```
pip install selenium
```

Here is the script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

pageLink = 'https://marketplace.realinsight.com/sales/details/367'

# Setup our chrome preferences.
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# Change this variable to the path of the chromedriver you downloaded.
chromedriver = "D:\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome( executable_path = chromedriver, chrome_options = chromeOptions )

driver.get( pageLink )

extractData = driver.find_element( By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/section[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]" )

print( extractData.text )
```